# Product involving Dirichlet characters $\prod_{i=1}^{\phi(m)}(1 - \frac{\chi_i(p)}{p^s}) =(1 - \frac{1}{p^{fs}})^{\frac{\phi(m)}{f}}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters

While working with divisors in cyclotomic extensions of $\mathbb{Q},$ I came across this identity:

Given a prime $p$ and an integer $m$ such that $(p,m) =1$, let $f$ be the smallest such the $p^f \equiv 1  \text{ mod } m$ where $p,m,f \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}.$

How can I prove that $$\prod_{i=1}^{\phi(m)}(1 - \frac{\chi_i(p)}{p^s}) =(1 - \frac{1}{p^{fs}})^{\frac{\phi(m)}{f}}, $$
 for any real number $s>1$ where the $\chi_i$ denote the $\phi(m)$ Dirichlet characters mod $m$ ?

I tried grouping the factors on the left into $\frac{\phi(m)}{f}$ groups of $f$ factors so each group product gives me one copy $(1 - \frac{1}{p^{fs}})$ but I have not yet figured out how to group the characters in order to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use that, 
$$ X^n - 1 = \prod_{\zeta} \left( X - \zeta\right)$$
Setting $X = p^s$ and dividing should give, 
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{p^{ns}} = \prod_{\zeta} \left( 1 - \frac{\zeta}{p^s} \right) $$
Then you use the fact that a character modulo $n$ produces the roots of unity (what we are calling $\zeta$, above) as its output values. The rest of the argument is a counting argument were you need to count how many times a Dirichlet character takes on a particular root of unity.

Comment: @I Love Mr. Paul, thank you! Give me a second to use your hint to prove the identity and I shall come back.

Comment: I got the whole proof with your lines of reasoning. Thank you!